# Conflicting post edit options under dashboard

Tags: content, dashboard

My dashboard(  It is multisite Installation ) section for pages and posts conflicts with options when there are morethan 5  data fields  .
For example :
I have these things under my Posts section in dashbpard :

**Title   Author     Categories     Tags     Comments    Date    Forum-Linked    Featured**

Because of these many fields these options conflicts each other like shown in the screen shot  :
**Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | Preview | Purge from Page Cache**

[image]

It is because of the increased fields like **forum-linked ,featured etc**. Some times when I install any other related plugins .The number of data fields increases and it becomes more ugly with the editing options .

Could any one suggest me a good Idea to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Columns can be hidden from view using the screen options tab.

#### On the upper right hand side of the dashboard click screen options

[image]

#### Un check any of the columns you want to hide.

[image]

#### Normally the edit options are displayed as horizontal text.  A plugin or other function has changed this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! It worked .The problem is causing because of the additional columns like forum linked,featured ,Id etc. Is there any way to fix the column width for Title column and reduce the column width for other columns( which uses less space actually) to entire Multi-site installation ?So that one need not use the screen options every time they edit.

Comment: @user402 Find the css the plugin uses to manipulate the columns and change the width.

Comment: I am not sure If I follow "Find the css the plugin " .Would you please be more specific .Are you referring any plugin?

Comment: I'm referring to the plugin that changes the columns in the dashboard.

Comment: I understand . I will do it